# Error en mostrar una snackBar en onRequestPermissionsResult

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Como se puede usar un snackbar dentro de `onRequestPermissionsResult` como necesita de una vista le asigno con `findViewById(R.id.root_view)`

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.root_view), getString(R.string.permission_request_advice),
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction(getString(R.string.permission_settings), new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    PermissionUtils.openInstalledAppDetailsActivity(RouteActivity.this);
                }
            })
            .show();

}
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.ViewGroup.getContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: ¿Comprobase si findViewById(R.id.root_view) devuelve null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es definitivamente el contexto.

Te sugiero obtener la vista root de esta forma:

```
 View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

y usarla en tu Snackbar:

```
Snackbar.make(rootView, getString(R.string.permission_request_advice),
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction(getString(R.string.permission_settings), new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    PermissionUtils.openInstalledAppDetailsActivity(RouteActivity.this);
                }
            })
            .show();
```

Comment: Buenas, ^_^ se me adelantaste, ahora mismo estaba escribiendo la respuesta

Comment: Buenas WebServeis ツ, estas dentro de una Activity imagino, prueba también con android.R.id.content .